# If there is no Jedi order, will the number of force sensitive increase significantly?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, jedi

Because the Jedi cannot marry and have children, just like a monk. All new Jedi were born in non-Force sensitive homes. For example, it's like in the world of *Harry Potter*, all wizards come from Muggle families like Hermione. Do they appear only through invisible inheritance and genetic mutation? Then the Jedi Order cut off every lineage of their blood, and hoped that the Force would bring them new people.

If there is no Jedi Order, all Force-sensitive people can marry and have children, and their children are also likely to be Force-sensitive. Force-sensitive people are also welcome. Will the number of Force-sensitive people increase significantly?

Comment: Given how few Jedi there were, it's unlikely a force sensitive would ever be on the same planet as another force sensitive

Comment: As long as one of the parents is force sensitive, the child has a high chance of being force sensitive. Like Luke, Leia and Ben Solo.

Comment: It all depends on how dominant a trait force sensitivity actually is. If it's totally dominant, it'll sweep through a community like wildfire in just a few tens of generations

Comment: One of the stupidest parts of the prequel movies is that the Jedi must be celibate. The Jedi were obviously aware of the midiclorians' role in force sensitivity and must have known that this sensitivity was heriditary. Hence, enforcing celibacy seems like a deliberate attempt to weed out force sensitivity in the galaxy, which makes very little sense. It seems to me that this detail was only included to make the love affair between Anakin and Padme illicit.

Comment: This really depends on the heritability as compared to the mututation rate of midichlorians, as well as how complex the genetic markers are for force sensitivity (how many alleles, and how complicated of a gene is responsible for each allele.) With a few basic assumptions, you could use standard genetics to help you answer this question. Thankfully, Lucas wrecked the mysticism by helpfully explaining midiclorians.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen I mean, the Jedi are all about avoiding strong feelings that may lead you to the dark side. Love is one of such feelings (as demonstrated with Anakin falling into the dark side). So yeah, celibacy makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be evidence supporting that with force sensitives having children, the number would increase. Courtesy of it seeming force-sensitivity is heritable by at least some degree (hard to say how dominant exactly).

For instance, Eeth Koth had a daughter after being kicked off the council - immediately after birth, the door was kicked in by Vader and Inquisitors and along with the execution of Koth, the child was said to be definitely force sensitive and taken away. Ben Solo was also obviously force sensitive inheriting it from his mother Leia - who inherited it along with her brother from their father. Then Jedi Master Braylon (from audio "star wars Dooku Jedi Lost") who had an illegitimate secret child while away, that inherited her force sensitivity.

And then spoilers for ROS but: there's also a granddaughter of Palpatine who inherited his powers a couple generations down. Although it's uncertain if her father did inherit those powers himself.

So while it's not going to be the case that every force-sensitive having a child would result in that child having force-sensitivity, it's reasonable to suspect there would be an increase with there certainly being at least *some* inheritability and some born who do (which is more than what was going on with no Jedi having children except a couple secretly, so an increase by default)

***However.***

There are other factors which might not help, with the Jedi gone.

As an example - Even with the Jedi present, there were cases of people trying to traffic force sensitive children for nefarious reasons: a crime cartel snatched a Padawan Eldra Kaitis to auction off and a very young Ahsoka also nearly got grabbed too as a child before Plo Koon found her.

So along with the heritability factor, how the environment of the galaxy at large develops post sequel trilogy is also important: and currently at this point with the last movie just released, that's unfortunately impossible to give more of an exact answer on.